# SqlTableDependency stops listening to changes after a while

Tags: sql, sql-server, iis, asp.net-web-api

I am using SqlTableDependency and SignalR in my ASP.NET WebAPI project for dispatching real-time notifications to the client app. Everything is working just fine. However, SqlTableDependency stops listening to database changes after a while.

My WebAPI project is running in the local IIS. I am not sure but I think the Idle Timeout in the IIS application pool is the root cause for the issue. IIS might be terminating the application after idle timeout causing SqlTableDependency watchdog to run and remove all DB objects (triggers, queues, etc.).

What would be a good strategy to tackle this problem? Is there a way to check if SqlTableDependency is still watching the table changes? So that if it's not, I can create a new instance of it. Or, is it good practice to just turn off idle timeout for my WebAPI project?

Any ideas or suggestions are highly welcomed.

Comment: I think you already identified the issue. If you have a timeout set , that is closing your connection to the db. To test your theory you could setup the timeout to 10 -30 seconds. If it stop listening do a refresh of the page, if it starts listening again then the timeout is the problem. A second problem could be that you are closing the connection to the db.

Comment: @ClaudioCorchez Thank you for your suggestions. When the SqlTableDependency stops listening to changes, refreshing the page is doing nothing. I have to restart IIS for it to start listening again.

Comment: if it stopped listening exactly after the number of seconds in the timeout I would suggest to remove it but that depends on the security you want to have on the page.